# why am i getting this IndexOutOfBoundsException error? pt2

Tags: java

so im currently trying to find the average of these rows and columns, and I've gotten the sum for all of them. But this error comes up as a result of this code

```
int e[][] = {{10,30, 50, 200},
             {60, 40,70, 55},
             {80, 5, 35, 100}};
    
      int sumRow = 0; 
      int sumCol = 0;           
      for (int r = 0; r < e.length; r++)
      { 
         for (int c = 0; c < e[r].length;c++)
         {
            sumRow = sumRow + e[r][c];
         }
         System.out.println(sumRow);
      } 
      
      for (int r = 0; r < e[r].length; r++)
      { 
         for (int c = 0; c < e.length;c++)
         {
            sumCol = sumCol + e[c][r];
         }
         System.out.println(sumCol);
      } 
}
```

the problem is at the start of the 2nd nested for loop, I'm very new to this, so if it's obvious, don't be surprised.

```
  for (int r = 0; r < e[r].length; r++)
```

this is where the problem comes up.

thank you for your help.

Comment: How many items are there in `e[r]`? How many items are there in `e`? Why are you looping _up to_ `e[r].length` items, and yet accessing items from `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is not jagged you can just use e[0].length. In your code e[r].length will check the length of the fourth row when r is 3 and your array does not have one so you can predetermine that by using e[0].length.

```
int e[][] = {{10, 30, 50, 200},
                 {60, 40, 70, 55},
                 {80, 5, 35, 100}};

    int sumRow = 0;
    int sumCol = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < e.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < e[r].length; c++) {
            sumRow = sumRow + e[r][c];
        }
        System.out.println(sumRow);
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < e[0].length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < e.length; c++) {
            sumCol = sumCol + e[c][r];
        }
        System.out.println(sumCol);
    }
```